# apache not working, shows a "404 page not found" error

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

i have been trying to set up apache2 on my ubuntu 16.04 but after successful install i get a `404 page not found` error whenever i type localhost in the browser. I have uninstalled and installed apache2 several times but the problem still persists.
This is the output of my /var/log/apache2/error.log file..

> [Tue Jun 26 02:20:52.809104 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1010:tid 139925306578816] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   [Tue Jun 26 02:20:58.753357 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1359:tid 139843231913856] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Tue Jun 26 02:20:58.753554 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1359:tid 139843231913856] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Do you also have an access.log showing where you made a request to localhost?

Comment: There is a file at `/var/log/apache2/access.log` but it's empty

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache

Comment: Did you actually install with `sudo apt install apache2` or from source code or some other method?  Also if you've made any configuration changes to Apache, please post those files.

Comment: i installed it using `sudo apt install apache2` and i've made no configuration changes. I have reinstalled it several times after doing purge remove but it is still the same

Comment: i have installed xampp but it gives me the same result when i try to access `http://localhost`